# Playing inilne video and user audio at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have a workout app and I am trying to play the exercise video inline (not full screen) on mute and allow the user to play their ipod or spotify music at the same time. Right now, it either freezes the video and lets the audio play or stops the audio and let the video play.

HTML:

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0px solid purple;border-radius:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:-8%;" ng-click="hidesimple();" on-swipe-right="prev()" on-swipe-left="next()">

    <video class="animatedw fadeIn delaylong" webkit-playsinline autoplay loop muted ng-src="{{keeper}}" style="width:101%;height:100%;border:2px solid white;border-radius:100px;z-index:1;">
    </video>

</div>
```

each video file is in a mp4 format

Thanks for the help :)